CDF of random variable with Poisson distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable with Poisson distribution and parameter $\lambda>0$. Prove that
$$
F_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n!}\int_\lambda^\infty\mathrm{d}t\; e^{-t}t^n\;&,\; &n\leq x\leq n+1\;,\;n\in\mathbb{N}\\
0\;&,\; &x<0
\end{cases}
$$

Here's what I tried
$$
\begin{align}
F_X(x) = \sum_{k\leq x}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\implies\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}F_X(x) &= \sum_{k\leq x}\left[k\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{k!}e^{-\lambda} - \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\right]\\
&= \sum_{1\leq k\leq x}\left[k\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{k!}e^{-\lambda} - \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\right]-1\\
&= \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}e^{-\lambda}\\
&\implies\\
F_X(x) &= \frac{1}{x!}\int_\lambda^\infty\mathrm{d}\xi\;\xi^xe^{-\xi}
\end{align}$$
And that's where I'm stuck. I don't know how I can go from this expression to the one in the problem's statement.
Any help is appreciated.

There is a typo. $\int_\lambda^\infty\mathrm{d}t\; e^{-1}t^n$ should be $\int_\lambda^\infty\mathrm{d}t\; e^{-t}t^n$.
Hint: $X$ takes only non-negative integer values. For $n \le x<n+1$ the event $(X \le x)$ is same as the event $(X \le n)$. So $F_X(x)= P(X\le n)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}P(X=k)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} e^{-\lambda} \frac {\lambda^{k}} {k!}$. To show that this is equal to the given expression, you have to compute $\int_\lambda^\infty\mathrm{d}t\; e^{-t}t^n$ using integration by parts $n$ times.

I've corrected it. I've copied the statement straight from the textbook, the typo was there then. Thanks for pointing that out.
